# Linear regression with parameters with different n

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, linear-regression

In order to do Simple Linear Regression I know that $ \bar{x} = 95$, $\sum_{i = 1}^7x_i^2 = 63245$, $\sum_{i=1}^{14}y_i = 626$, $\sum_{i=1}^{14}y_i^2 = 56132$, $\sum_{i=1}^{14}x_iy_i = 59564$.

I know how to calculate the Linear Regression Line, but in this case we can see that there are only $n = 7$ results for $x$ and 14 for $y$. My question is, what am I supposed to consider when calculating the parameters in order to have the $\bar{y}$, $\sum_{i = 1}^nx_i^2 - n\bar{x}^2$, $\sum_{i = 1}^ny_i^2 - n\bar{y}^2$, $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_iy_i - n\bar{x}\bar{y}$ since one is calculated considering $n = 7$ and the other is calculated considering $n_y = 14$?

I also have the 1-to-1 index correspondence from these vector:

$x = (90, 92, 94, 95, 96, 98, 100), y = (83, 83, 87, 92, 93, 94, 94)$

such that $x_1 = 90 \rightarrow 83 = y_1$, $x_2 = 92 \rightarrow 83 = y_2$, etc

Comment: What is the difference between $\sum_{i=1}^{14}y_i^2$ and$ \sum_{i=1}^{14}y_i y_i$? Also, why do you have $7$ results for $x$ and $14$? Lastly, for an index $i$ how an $x_i$ is associated to an $y_i$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I added the correspondence to the question (I didn't know it would be relevant). And corrected the mistake you pointed out to me

Comment: In $\sum_{i=1}^{14} x_i y_i$, there are $x_i$ for $i > 7$.  How is that possible if there are only $7$ results for $x$?

Comment: @user6247850 I'm coming to the conclusion that this is a mistake form the book